# Adding deep folders in git

Tags: git

When programming in java it is common to have file structures as deep as

```
com/company/project/folder/subfolder
```

So when adding a file you have to type

```
git add com/company/project/folder/subfolder/SomeAwesomeClass.java
```

Is there a faster way? like some sort of `git add-if-matches SomeAwesomeClass.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
git add *AwesomeClass.java
```

But this will add all files with that name under the current directory or any of its subdirectories as deep as possible.

If you want to add only a specific file inside a specific directory you can try:

```
git add *subfolder/SomeAwesomeClass.java
```

You can also try the following to add all files on a specific directory:

```
git add *subfolder/*
```

Note that there is no spaces before or after the asterisk symbol.

I have tried these on Mac OS X with the same exact scenario and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to add the whole subdirectory, then you can simply git add the directory

```
git add com
```

If you really only want to add that one class, then the easiest solution is to do the Unix thing and compose commands together.  In this case, the `find` command is the thing which is really good at finding files with a given name.  You can pass the output of find to git in bash by surrounding the find command with `$()`

```
git add $(find . -name SomeAwesomeClass.java)
```

Comment: Have you tried [interactive staging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging)? This is exactly the use case it's meant for. `git add -i` pops up a menu along with a list of changed/untracked files. To add 2 files from even a long list of long paths, what you would type would be similar to these 9 key presses: `u<enter>1<enter>7<enter><enter>q<enter>`. The more paths you have to add, the more typing you save. You can also choose patch adding, diffing, and several other things from the menu.

Comment: @GaryFixler  Thanks.  I never knew about interactive staging.  It is probably the right tool for the job in almost all cases.  Does it also scale when you have hundreds of untracked files?

Comment: Yes. For example, to add modified files, after hitting `u` or `2` to choose '2: update' from the menu, you could type `3<enter>` to add the 3rd file in the list, or you could type `1 2 5<enter>` to add files 1, 2, and 5, or you could even type `3-27<enter>` to add files 3 through 27, or even `1 4 6-13 25-27 34<enter` to add those individual files and ranges thereof in one go. You can also remove your additions there by prepending a minus sign to each, i.e. `-1 -6-13<enter>` to take those back out of the list. It's a very fast way to stage things.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type `git add com` unless there are other files in the directory structure that you don't want to add..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just cooked up a little recipe. A simple bash function that you can add to you .bash_profile

```
function add(){
    git add $(git status --porcelain | grep "$1" | cut -c 4-)
}
```

To use it you can just call `add something` and it will add any files that match, so if you have 2 files:

```
com/company/project/folder/subfoler/AwesomeClass.java
com/company/project/folder/subfoler/subfolder/CoolClass.java
```

You can call

```
add Awesome
```

And it will add the AwesomeClass.java